# load map only single city on google map android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show map only one city or country in my android app. How can I do it ?
I do not need to load map of all world

image 1

[image: image 1]

image 2

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see only country or city you can use its latlng bound its focus on the particular city or country when user come first time here all country latlng bound https://gist.github.com/graydon/11198540

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to be familiar with Google Map API (create an API key, import it to your project, etc.)

Then, get the LatLng of the city you want, and on the moveCamera method, pass to it a good zooming (it's a float). For exemple, when your widget is beeing launched, call something like : `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(yourCoords, 10f))`

If you don't want / need to allow any user interaction with your map, just set the parameter "`liteMode`" to `true` inside your XML (or programatically), it will generate a bitmap of your desired location.

Bye.